# Do we need a transit visa for a two-hour layover at London Heathrow airport?

Tags: uk, transit-visas, london, lhr

While travelling from India to USA via London Heathrow Airport with British Airways, is there a need to procure transit visa for the UK?

I read https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa. There is nothing in this link that exempts me from requiring a visa. But I have traveled to USA via London Heathrow Airport before without transit visa. Nobody ever asked me to show a transit visa. So I am very surprised that a transit visa may be required.

Does anyone know for sure if a transit visa is required to go from India to USA via London Heathrow Airport?

Edit: The [Check UK Visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) tool showed that I do not need transit visa if I am not passing through border control because I have USA visa.

Comment: When you start your journey toward London your airline will check your paperwork and they check that you have the transfer visa if you need one. You would not get to London if you need one but do not have it.

Comment: "There is nothing in this link that exempts me from requiring a visa." Have you actually used the visa check tool? U.S. visa holders and permanent residents are exempt from transit visa requirement (at least when travelling to the USA).

Comment: Note: transit visa do not depend of origin or destination. Originating the flight in India doesn't matter, but your citizenship matter. Note: it is not mandatory for a country to control the visa/passport (especially on transit). They may check just few people (and maybe according API [Advanced Passenger Information] data you must provide before to flight.